# Actually bean counting: Find standard deviation given population ratio, size of sample and number of samples.

Tags: probability-distributions, standard-deviation

I've been Googling and raking my brain over college statistics for the past hour, but can't seem to find a solution for this particular situation:

So, I have a lot of beans (assume an **infinite sized population** of beans) **evenly mixed** at a ratio of **1 red bean : 100 green beans**.

Say I take **30 random samples of 4200 beans each**. What would be the **standard deviation of the number of red beans** these samples?

Ultimately, I need to create some sort of visual probability distribution curve that shows the expected distribution of red beans across 30 random samples. What formulas should I use for this particular situation?

Any guidance at all would be deeply appreciated!